# Не полностью выводится содержимое словаря

Tags: python, django

Если создать в бд несколько ошибок, принадлежащие одному проекту, то выведется только первая из них, а остальные нет. В чём проблема?

модель:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Error(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    programmer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    possible_solution = models.TextField()
    current_state = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Активно")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

представление:

```
def bugTracker(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    errors = Error.objects.all()
    bug_list = zip(projects, errors)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'bug_list': bug_list})
```

шаблон:

```
     {% for projects, errors in bug_list %}
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{ errors.name }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ projects.name }}
          </td>
         ...
        </tr>  
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Очевидно, в том, что bug_list у вас содержит пары "один проект - одна ошибка", потому что вы zip зачем-то используете

Answer (score 0):

zip в данном случае не поможет. ORM django умеет выгружать связанные объекты, для понимания модернизируем немного модель, вью и выведем всё это в шаблоне.

модель (добавим related_name):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Error(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_errors')
    programmer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    possible_solution = models.TextField()
    current_state = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Активно")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py - оптимизируем запрос и выгрузим связанные объекты:

```
def bugTracker(request):
    projects = Project.objects.prefetch_related('project_errors').all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'projects': projects})
```

Шаблон:

```
{% for project in projects %}
    {{ project.name }}
    {% for error in project.project_errors.all %}
        {{ error.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Документация:

1. [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
2. [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: Да, это работает, но нужно, чтобы выводилось в таблице построчно, а второй цикл выведет всё в одну строку

Comment: Вывод построчно уже регулируется html, можно `{{ error.name }}` обернуть в `<p>`. Как именно стилизовать и отображать информацию - на ваше усмотрение, это фронтэнд часть.

Comment: А можно это всё как-то вывести одним массивом, как в случае с zip?

Comment: как вы представляете себе структуру данных, которую хотите вывести? потому что ваши данные на данный момент выгружаются одним массивом, состоящим из "проектов", при этом каждый "проект" содержат связанные "ошибки". вам нужно определиться с требованиями.

Comment: Залил картинку, чтобы было наглядно видно: https://ibb.co/gDBojH В идеале было бы запихнуть всю инфу в одно место и пройтись по каждому пункту по очереди, тогда и проблем с форматированием не было бы

Comment: Проблема не с форматированием, а с реализацией ваших требований. Возможно, стоит сделать следующую ахритектуру: https://pastebin.com/XTNg85E3

Answer (score 0):

В общем из-за своей неопытности работы с джанго и с базами данных в целом, мне почему-то не приходило в голову, что поле с отношением можно использовать для вывода. И поэтому получается всё получается легко и просто:

представление:

```
def bugTracker(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"bugs":Error.objects.all()})
```

шаблон:

```
{% for bug in bugs %}
  <tr>  
     <td> {{ bug.project }} </td>
     <td> {{ bug.name }} </td>
     <td> {{ bug.current_state }} </td>
     <td> {{ bug.programmer }} </td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```